# Saving AVI files in C++ after creating

Tags: c++, visual-c++, save, avi, vfw

I'm using Wischik's example code for creating AVI files, however after I run the code and it exits successfully no AVI file is created.  I looked through the code and cannot find where it writes/saves/creates an AVI file on your computer.  Does anyone know where the code saves AVI file or if it doesn't, a way to make it save the AVI file created to your computer?  Thanks

link to source code here
[Wischik source code](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/avi_utils.html)

Comment: The file is created by AVIFileOpen, but this function is not present in the supplied source. What other libraries do you use?

Comment: i use the vfw library, i #include <vfw.h> and link to it in preferences

Comment: Ok, that is a header file, does it declare AVIFileOpen? There might be some clues in it. If not, what libraries or other object files are you linking this code with?

Comment: it should I believe, vfw is the video for windows library so can't actually look at the header file personally I think.  also in avil_utils.cpp I link #define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "avi_utils.h"
#include <vfw.h>, and in my main file I link #define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include "avi_utils.h"
#include <vfw.h>, and in the avi_utils.h header #ifndef _avi_utils_H
#define _avi_utils_H
#include <Vfw.h>

Answer (score 0):

You should find test.avi in the project directory. Since you know it's name, you could also use Windows explorer to search for it.

To examine further, (assuming you are using VC++), goto 
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories,
and Show Directories for Include files.
That will tell you where the headers are.

Alternatively, set a break point at the line where AVIFileOpen is called, and follow the execution path to see what it does.